# using sed script to combine part of current line with part of next line every other line

Tags: linux, unix, sed

So what I want to do it combine the first part of one line with the first part of the next, separated by colon for every other line.

The input data is below and I am struggling to make it work.

This is what I want it to look like (WANT THIS):

```
Albania:Armenia
Angola:Antarctica
Argentina:American Samoa
```

This is the input:

```
Albania,EU,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albania
Armenia,AS,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenia
Angola,AF,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angola
Antarctica,AN,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica
Argentina,SA,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentina
American Samoa,OC,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Samoa
Austria,EU,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria
Australia,OC,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia
Aruba,NA,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aruba
Azerbaijan,AS,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijan
Bosnia and Herzegovina,EU,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosnia_and_Herzegovina
Barbados,NA,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbados
Bangladesh,AS,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangladesh
Belgium,EU,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgium
Burkina Faso,AF,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burkina_Faso
Bulgaria,EU,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgaria
Bahrain,AS,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahrain
Burundi,AF,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burundi
Benin,AF,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benin
Saint Barthelemy,NA,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Barthelemy
```

What I have come up with so far is this, using N to get the next line, and it partially works. The "junk" of the first name is gone but the "junk" of the 2nd is still there. (This is a sed script and I must have a sed script that runs with all the other sed scripts so no awk or anything)

```
s/,..,.+//
{N
s/\n/:/
p
}
```

My attempt produces this output:

```
Azerbaijan:Bosnia and Herzegovina,EU,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosnia_and_Herzegovina
Barbados:Bangladesh,AS,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangladesh
Belgium:Burkina Faso,AF,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burkina_Faso
Bulgaria:Bahrain,AS,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahrain
Burundi:Benin,AF,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/,.*//;N;s/\n/:/;s/,.*//
```

Remove everything after comma, append next line, replace newline with colon, remove everything after comma.

Comment: Oh my gosh that was quick thanks looks like it is perfect

Comment: Yep, better than `paste -d: <(cut -d, -f1 inputfile| sed '$d' ) <(cut -d, -f1 inputfile| sed '1d' ) `, upvoted.